# How to solve 'collect2: ld returned 1 exit status '?

Tags: linux, hyperlink

when I build my source code in  linux  I got an error like

```
qstring.cpp:(.text+0x2c01): undefined reference to `terminate(void)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

`terminate` is defined in the C++ standard library, so make sure that you're linking that in.  Assuming you're using gcc to compile, you should use the `g++` executable to compile your source code, *not* the `gcc` executable:

```
g++ source.cc -o output
```

When executed as `g++`, the linker automatically links in the C++ standard library (libstdc++) for you.  If you instead execute gcc as plain `gcc`, or you directly invoke the linker `ld`, then you need to add `-lstdc++` yourself to link in the library, e.g.:

```
gcc source.cc -o output -lstdc++  # Compile directly from source
ld source1.o source2.o -o output -lstdc++  # Link together object files
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out which object file or library `terminate` lives in and include it in your compile/link command.

If it's in an object or source file, just give it to your `gcc` (assuming you're actually *using* `gcc`, if not, the method will probably be similar) command as per normal. If it's in a library, you should look into the `-L` (library path) and `-l` (library name) options.

Answer (score -3):

`void terminate(void) { raise(9); }`